# Can't enable or disable extensions in Firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox, firefox-extensions

I try to enable or disable extensions in Firefox.  It says "Restart Firefox to complete your changes".  I press the restart button and it restarts.  When it comes back up, the extension is unchanged.  How do I fix this?

This isn't just one specific Add-on.  I've tried disabling lots of add-ons at once.  Some of them lose their icons and stop working, for one session, but they are still shown, with a "Disable" button, in Add-ons, and they come back fully when I restart Firefox.

If I go into safe mode, tell it to disable all extensions, and then disable them all manually, their functionality no longer exists, but the Add-ons still shows them with "Disable" buttons, but with many missing icons:

[image]

If I then disable an extension and restart, all the ones I disabled are back to normal enabled again.

Firefox 3.6.13 in Windows 7

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following methods:

- Try Removing the Add-on via Safe Mode
- Checkout Add/Remove Programs
- Remove the Add-on Manually

Please read this [article](http://www.firefoxfacts.com/2008/12/23/trouble-removing-a-firefox-add-on/) for more details.

If that doesn't help, uninstall Firefox completely (which deletes your whole profile and settings) and reinstall from scratch. That should solve the problem.

Comment: It's all Add-ons, not just one.

Comment: Did you try to enable/disable them in Safe Mode?

Comment: Yes, I disabled all of them in Safe Mode and the same thing happened.

Comment: Then I recommend you back up your bookmarks and make a clean install.

Comment: I already tried installing again over top of the existing installation, it didn't change anything.

Comment: By clean install, I mean uninstalling Firefox completely (which deletes your whole profile and settings) and reinstalling from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following using the [FEBE](http://softwarebychuck.com/febe/febe.html) addon (search febe in addons to install):-

```
Installed FEBE addon 
Backup all addons/extensions through FEBE    
Restore all addons via FEBE
```

Now all addons are re-enabled and working fine.
Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you haven't got more than one instance of Firefox running

Comment: There's only one instance